# Why showing double vhost-2473 in KVM?

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, cpu, kvm-virtualization, top

[why system showing double vhost-2473?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo0kM.jpg) I have installed KVM and created a Guest machine with two interfaces on the Ubuntu-14.04 server. When I keep running the Guest machine, the Host machine showing two vhost-2473 in the $ top command that consuming extra %CPU and %memory. Anyone can explain it why? Attached picture. N.B: I used two bridge networks in this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not much to explain here as [Vhost Architecture](http://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/09/qemu-internals-vhost-architecture.html) by Stefan Hajnoczi covers it so well.

TL;DR:

> "vhost ... creates a kernel thread ... to handle I/O events and
>   perform the device emulation."

And the number of devices defines the number of worker threads.
So I have usually one, and if I add two more vhost network interfaces I have three then.